# Jenkins slave cannot clone git repo

Tags: git, jenkins, amazon-ec2

When trying to build a job which involves connecting to a git repo the jenkins slave is unable to clone
the repo.
When trying the same with the master it works. The slave is set up on an AWS EC2 Instance (Linux). 
Here is a piece of the console log:

```
Started by user ...<br>
Running as SYSTEM<br>
Building remotely on Jenkins-Slave (Test) in workspace /home/jenkins-slave-01/workspace/TestSlave<br>
Selected Git installation does not exist. Using Default<br>
The recommended git tool is: NONE<br>
using credential d7068211-a7f3-4eef-8c5c-4ba6c23d3766<br>
Cloning the remote Git repository<br>
Cloning repository ... <br>
 git init /home/jenkins-slave-01/workspace/TestSlave # timeout=10<br>
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'<br>
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init /home/jenkins-slave-01/workspace/TestSlave

[...] 

hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing git command: git init /home/jenkins-slave-01/workspace/TestSlave
```

What do i have to do in order to let the slave uses git and clone the repo?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure your instance has internet access, Routing to internet gateway or nat gateway

Comment: It looks like git is not installed on jenkins worker

Comment: looks like it doesn't even clone, it is stuck at "git init". Check if that operation went well or not

Answer (score 1):

The steps to install the Git client on the Jenkins slave, and the Git plugin on Jenkins.

1. Check the security groups for SSH for the EC2 instance on AWS.
2. Install the Git client on the Jenkins slave.
3. Configure the Git client on the Jenkins slave.
4. Install a Git plugin on Jenkins.
5. Configure the Git plugin on Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to install git on the EC2 instance on which the jenkins slave run.
I simply forget about that.